# Sending same form multiple times with Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to register 3 students in same registration form. When one student is registered, I want to register another student with the same form, just having different data in the same fields.

```
package Database;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Bayer extends Landindpage {

    public  void Bayerfill (){ 
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\workspace\\chromeDriver\\chromeDriver.exe");
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://qa-0.ls.vu/v2/landing-page/bayer/en");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/form/div[1]/div")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/form/div[1]/div/select/option[2]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/form/div[2]/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("Emmaname");    
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/form/div[2]/div[2]/input")).sendKeys("Mohaname");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/form/div[3]/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("0221-1234567");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/form/div[3]/div[2]/input")).sendKeys("aali3005@gmai.com");

        driver.findElementById("submitButton").click();
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is problem you facing? Be clear

Comment: Above code is my data i'm stuck at logic how can i insert data in same fields with different data like first time register one student that above code mention and there fields next time an loop implement and change the value dynamically

Answer (score 1):

When you have all your code in one method like this, it's not very reusable. Which means that for next use case you're likely to just copy/paste the same code and then alter it slightly. Repeating yourself like that is bad practice.

Instead of having everything in one method, you should refactor things to be a bit more generic. The smaller modules you manage to break the functionality into, the more likely they will be usable for the next use case that you start working on.

Create a class for your student details:

```
public class Student {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String email;

    // generate setters and getters
}
```

Change your class to handle commanding the WebDriver with dynamic input:

```
package Database;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Bayer extends Landindpage {
    private static final String FORM_URL = "http://qa-0.ls.vu/v2/landing-page/bayer/en";

    private static final String SOME_DIV_XPATH = "/html/body/div[4]/div/form/div[1]/div";
    private static final String SELECT_XPATH = "/html/body/div[4]/div/form/div[1]/div/select/option[2]";
    private static final String FIRST_NAME_XPATH = "/html/body/div[4]/div/form/div[2]/div[1]/input"
    private static final String LAST_NAME_XPATH = "/html/body/div[4]/div/form/div[2]/div[2]/input";
    private static final String PHONE_NUMBER_XPATH = "/html/body/div[4]/div/form/div[3]/div[1]/input";
    private static final String EMAIL_XPATH = "/html/body/div[4]/div/form/div[3]/div[2]/input";

    private static final String SUBMIT_ID = "submitButton";

    private ChromeDriver driver;

    public Bayer() { 
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    public void loadForm() {
      driver.get(FORM_URL);
    }

    public void fillUpForm(Student student) {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(SOME_DIV_XPATH)).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(SELECT_XPATH)).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(FIRST_NAME_XPATH)).sendKeys(student.getFirstName());    
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(LAST_NAME_XPATH)).sendKeys(student.getLastName());
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(PHONE_NUMBER_XPATH)).sendKeys(student.getPhoneNumber());
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(EMAIL_XPATH)).sendKeys(student.getEmail());
    }

    public void submitForm() {
        driver.findElementById(SUBMIT_ID).click();
    }
}
```

Create your students and have control flow in a third class:

```
public RegistrationFlowController {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\workspace\\chromeDriver\\chromeDriver.exe");

        List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

        Student student = new Student();
        student.setFirstName("Emmaname");
        student.setLastName("Mohaname");
        student.setPhoneNumber("0221-1234567");
        student.setEmail("aali3005@gmai.com");
        students.add(student);

        // create other students

        Bayer registrationPage = new Bayer();

        for (Student student : students) {
            registrationPage.loadForm();
            registrationPage.fillUpForm(student);
            registrationPage.submitForm();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm stuck again and much confused :( now sir your given support is so meaningful for me but i'm new at this platform

Comment: Which platform is that? This is pretty basic Java, so I guess you mean Java in general? Perhaps you shouldn't try such a complex case as your first application, but play around with simpler features first to familiarize yourself with the language.

Comment: I'm Working on java Selenium test automation

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, have a test data in an array 
Secondly, create a method in java which accepts driver and test data as arguments

Then until the test data size finish loop the testMethod and pass driver and test data as parameters

Don't forget to load the page where forms resides after submitting once.

Comment: If it is not clear please let us know, will try to give you suedo code

Comment: ok kindly if you don't mind u can give an example or write down a code for help please

Comment: kindly if you have suedo code kindly write down or show here please

Answer (score 0):

```
String testData[][] = {{"Emmaname","Mohaname","0221-1234567","aali3005@gmai.com"},{"Emmaname123","Mohaname123","0221-4321","test1235@gmai.com"}}
        for(String[] strings:testData){
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/form/div[1]/div")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/form/div[1]/div/select/option[2]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/form/div[2]/div[1]/input")).sendKeys(strings[0]);    
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/form/div[2]/div[2]/input")).sendKeys(strings[2]);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/form/div[3]/div[1]/input")).sendKeys(strings[3]);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/form/div[3]/div[2]/input")).sendKeys(strings[4]);

            driver.findElementById("submitButton").click();
        }
```

Comment: Yes you can add in your `Bayerfill()` method. You can upvote or marked as exact answer if it really helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are beginner, you use the following methods (you need to modify the code to make it work). This code can be helpful for you to understand dataProvider annotations, so later try to explore how to use DataProvider annotations.

**Points to be remember while learning selenium:**
1) Try to split your data and webelements
2) If possible read data from an external methods / file 
3) Create web elements using page factory

```
public void fillForm(String firstName, String lastName, String phoneNumber, String email) {

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/form/div[1]/div")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/form/div[1]/div/select/option[2]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/form/div[2]/div[1]/input")).sendKeys(firstName);    
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/form/div[2]/div[2]/input")).sendKeys(lastName);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/form/div[3]/div[1]/input")).sendKeys(phoneNumber);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/form/div[3]/div[2]/input")).sendKeys(email);

            driver.findElementById("submitButton").click();
}


    public void readData(Object[][] data)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j < data.length; j++){
                String firstName = (String)data[i][j];
                String lastName = (String)data[i][j];
                String phoneNumber = (String)data[i][j];
                String email= (String)data[i][j];
                fillForm(firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, email);
            }
        }
    }



public Object[][] getData() {
    //Rows - Number of times your test has to be repeated.
    //Columns - Number of parameters in test data.
    Object[][] data = new Object[4][4];

    // 1st row
    data[0][0] = "Emmaname";
    data[0][1] = "Mohaname";
    data[0][2] = "0221-1234567";
    data[0][3] ="emmaname@test.com";

    // 2nd row
    data[1][0] = "Emmaname123";
    data[1][1] = "Mohaname123";
    data[1][2] = "0221-4321";
    data[1][3] ="emmaname@test.com";

    // 3rd row
    data[2][0] = "abcdef";
    data[2][1] = "ghijkl";
    data[2][2] = "012345";
    data[2][3] ="emmaname@test.com";

    // 4rd row
    data[3][0] = "abcdef";
    data[3][1] = "ghijkl";
    data[3][2] = "012345";
    data[3][3] ="emmaname@test.com";

    return data;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a 2D array and put your test data values inside that, write a for loop and put your code to insert data and submit inside that loop.

Alternately you can also store these test data into an excel file , read tat excel file in your script using Apache POI/jxl and write a loop to insert data.

Comment: can you write down an example kindly

Comment: Adding as another answer